# Alert team members of SVN commit?

Tags: svn

I'm hosting my own svn repository on ubuntu 8.04.  Is there a way for svn to send emails to team members whenever a commit has happened?

If coding is required, the only language I'm able to use on a linux server is PHP.  So I could write a php script to be triggered by svn.

Can anyone tell me how to hook up my php script to an svn commit?  Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913/how-do-i-make-subversion-svn-send-email-on-checkins

Comment: yes, taht link you gave is what i'm looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way of doing this is to implement the [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks). But to be clear - the tons of emails will be annoying.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look into [Commit Monitor](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/). This is a windows-only solution I believe, but it allows your team members to "opt-in" to alerts, by checking the repository every 30 minutes or so.

Comment: +1. good advice. despite the fact that it is for windows only (never tried this with Wine) - it's much better than emails. i have been using it for about an year.

Comment: It's great as it does not require access to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can simple to do, read this pages:

1. [petefreitag](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/244.cfm)
2. [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1)

This web links describing how to use subversion hooks, and what types of her exist and how to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also monitor your repositories with [WebSVN](http://websvn.info) (a PHP based svn repository browser) and a RSS reader of your choice.