# email error in SVN notify

Tags: svn, email

we have installed subversion in cent os linux, we use svn notify for commit emails, our problem is the o/p of commit mails in mail clients like thunderbird and outlook express are fine. Whereas if we view the same commit mails on Microsoft outlook 2007 and outlook 2010, the commit mail is in incorrect format. Any idea to solve this. Please help us..

AS far as we are concerned this is the better mailer for SVN in linux than any other. If there is any other better mailer for linux then pls do let me know

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 0):

As said in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924/1374267), you'd better use the [post-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) to send mails in the format that suits your needs. You'll have better control on things such as formatting using such a solution.

You can find on the SVN doc a sample script ([commit-email.rb](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/commit-email.rb)) that sends an email after each commit:.