# Receving a mail contains file name changed along with details in mail itself

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, shutdown-hook

I have one query is that I have a team of 10 developers which is use to commit the code at different intervals of time in SVN repository so in order to know what diifernt files have been commuted I have put the shutdown post hook in the script I have added my mail Id such that if any file is been added then a mail from unix box will be sent to me contains revision and file name that is been changed.

Now please advise is there any script I can add which along with the file name in the mail format will also provide the content that what lines have been added and what lines have been deleted in red blue color such that in mail itself I can see along with the file names the content also , please advise for such scripts that I can add in my SVN repository I will add such script at trunk level itself.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly seems like a duplicate of [How do I make Subversion (SVN) send email on checkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913/how-do-i-make-subversion-svn-send-email-on-checkins)

I'm not sure if there are any post-commit scripts that output HTML mail that colorizes the diff, but there are an awful lot of email notification post-commit scripts floating around out there.

I didn't see it mentioned on that other question but Subversion has a python post-commit hook script called mailer.py that is included in the tools part of the Subversion source distribution that can be used, you can find it online here:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/mailer/

It also doesn't have the color coding you mention.