# What is a pre-revprop-change hook in SVN, and how do I create it?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I wanted to edit a log comment in the repository browser and received an error message that no pre-revprop-change hook exists for the repository. Besides having a scary name, what is a pre-revprop-change hook, and how do I create it?

Comment: now this link is the second one, just after a link to this question :)

Comment: The link about leads to VERY outdated SVNBook 1.0. The current one is 1.7 and 1.8 (nightly): http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Basically it's a script that is launched before unversioned property is modified on the repository, so that you can manage more precisely what's happening on your repository.

There are templates in the SVN distrib for different hooks, located in the /hooks subdirectory (*.tmpl that you have to edit and rename depending on your OS, to activate).

Comment: All the instructions are in the hook template script. If you need the hook for an `svnsync` mirror, then the default script will need to be changed, because it only allows changes to svn:log. Svnsync changes more than this, so I simply put an `exit 0` in there to allow all property changes (since this is a mirror for me only).

Comment: ... then save it as `pre-revprop-change` to the same directory and make it executable for the web server user (on Linux).

Answer (score 217):

For Windows, here's a link to an example batch file that only allows changes to the log message (not other properties):

http://ayria.livejournal.com/33438.html

Basically copy the code below into a text file and name it `pre-revprop-change.bat` and save it in the `\hooks` subdirectory for your repository.

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Set all parameters. Even though most are not used, in case you want to add
:: changes that allow, for example, editing of the author or addition of log messages.
set repository=%1
set revision=%2
set userName=%3
set propertyName=%4
set action=%5

:: Only allow the log message to be changed, but not author, etc.
if /I not "%propertyName%" == "svn:log" goto ERROR_PROPNAME

:: Only allow modification of a log message, not addition or deletion.
if /I not "%action%" == "M" goto ERROR_ACTION

:: Make sure that the new svn:log message is not empty.
set bIsEmpty=true
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('find /V ""') do (
set bIsEmpty=false
)
if "%bIsEmpty%" == "true" goto ERROR_EMPTY

goto :eof

:ERROR_EMPTY
echo Empty svn:log messages are not allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_PROPNAME
echo Only changes to svn:log messages are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_ACTION
echo Only modifications to svn:log revision properties are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1
```

Comment: Could have linked to the version there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155/common-types-of-subversion-hooks/68850#68850. I wrote that hook and posted it on SVN forum a while ago. I guess I should have put some credits in the hook comments.

Comment: I'm using this script with VisualSVN 2.0.8 and TortoiseSVN 1.6.11 and it works nicely.

Comment: You can edit hooks in VisualSVN by right-clicking your repository name in VisualSVN Server and selecting "Properties...". You'll see a "Hooks" tab. In there you'll see the different types of hooks available. Select the right one, click "Edit" and paste the above code into it. Hope that helps VisualSVN users!

Comment: Worked for me disabling line: if /I not "%action%" == "M" goto ERROR_ACTION. Other way, it kept saying only modifications allowed.

Comment: Quick and dirty method for windows is to create an empty file called hooks\pre-revprop-change.bat

Comment: This continues to work in VisualSVN `3.5.6` & TortoiseSVN `1.9.4`.

Comment: I have created an enhancement to that script, which saves the old and the new log message to a text file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66366955

Answer (score 22):

For Linux to allow the edition of a log comment,

- locate the file `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` in the `hooks` directory of your repository
- copy the file to the same directory, renaming it to `pre-revprop-change`
- give execute permission to the file (for the server user, e.g. `www-data`)

**Edited:** (thanks to lindes)

- after that you might have to edit the script to return an exit value of `0` for the kind of edits, that you want to allow.

Comment: This is insufficient... one still needs to change the exit values appropriately.  But I found it helpful anyway, as a pointer to the right place to look... which some of other answers were lacking, or giving windows-specific answers to.  So thanks for this.

Comment: I am pretty sure, in my Ubuntu Linux version copying and giving permission was enough . But I don't know for sure anymore. I have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm certain it didn't work for me as-is when I tried it 2 days ago, and added this comment.  With the edit, though, this answer works for me.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the link to the stack overflow question with many common hooks [Common Types of Subversion Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155/common-types-of-subversion-hooks/68850#68850), including the original source of the `pre-revprop-change` hook for Windows cross-posted here.

You should refer there as they may get improved over time.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks #patmortech

And I added your code which "only the same user can change his code".

```
:: Only allow editing of the same user.
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ( 
'"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnlook.exe" author -r %revision% %repository%') do ( 
set orgAuthor=%%a
)
if /I not "%userName%" == "%orgAuthor%" goto ERROR_SAME_USER
```

Answer (score 7):

The name of the hook script is not so scary if you manage decipher it: it's **pre revision property change hook**. In short, the purpose of [`pre-revprop-change`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) hook script is to control changes of unversioned (revision) properties and to send notifications (e.g. to send an email when revision property is changed).

There are 2 types of properties in Subversion:

- versioned properties (e.g `svn:needs-lock` and `svn:mime-type`) that can be set on files and directories,
- unversioned (revision) properties (e.g. `svn:log` and `svn:date`) that are set on repository *revisions*.

Versioned properties have history and can be manipulated by ordinary users who have Read / Write access to a repository. On the other hand, unversioned properties do not have any history and serve mostly maintenance purpose. For example, if you commit a revision it immediately gets `svn:date` with UTC time of your commit, `svn:author` with your username and `svn:log` with your commit log message (if you specified any).

As I already specified, the purpose of `pre-revprop-change` hook script is to control changes of revision properties. You don't want everyone who has access to a repository to be able to modify all revision properties, so changing revision properties is forbidden by default. To allow users to change properties, you have to create `pre-revprop-change` hook.

The simplest hook can contain just one line: `exit 0`. It will allow any authenticated user to change any revision property and it should not be used in real environment. On Windows, you can use batch script or PowerShell-based script to implement some logic within `pre-revprop-change` hook.

This PowerShell script allows to change `svn:log` property only and denies empty log messages.

```
# Store hook arguments into variables with mnemonic names
$repos    = $args[0]
$rev      = $args[1]
$user     = $args[2]
$propname = $args[3]
$action   = $args[4]

# Only allow changes to svn:log. The author, date and other revision
# properties cannot be changed
if ($propname -ne "svn:log")
{
  [Console]::Error.WriteLine("Only changes to 'svn:log' revision properties are allowed.")
  exit 1
}

# Only allow modifications to svn:log (no addition/overwrite or deletion)
if ($action -ne "M")
{
  [Console]::Error.WriteLine("Only modifications to 'svn:log' revision properties are allowed.")
  exit 2
}

# Read from the standard input while the first non-white-space characters
$datalines = ($input | where {$_.trim() -ne ""})
if ($datalines.length -lt 25)
{
  # Log message is empty. Show the error.
  [Console]::Error.WriteLine("Empty 'svn:log' properties are not allowed.")
  exit 3
}

exit 0
```

This batch script allows only "svnmgr" user to change revision properties:

```
IF "%3" == "svnmgr" (goto :label1) else (echo "Only the svnmgr user may change revision properties" >&2 )

exit 1
goto :eof

:label1
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save the changes on the log messages, use the batch script from the answer above from @patmortech (https://stackoverflow.com/a/468475),
who copied the script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850,
and add these lines between `if "%bIsEmpty%" == "true" goto ERROR_EMPTY` and `goto :eofbefore`:

```
set outputFile=%repos%\log-change-history.txt

echo User '%user%' changes log message in rev %rev% on %date% %time%.>>%outputFile%
echo ----- Old message: ----->>%outputFile%
svnlook propget --revprop %repos% svn:log -r %rev% >>%outputFile%
echo.>>%outputFile%
echo ----- New message: ----->>%outputFile%
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('find /V ""') do (echo %%g >>%outputFile%)
echo ---------->>%outputFile%
echo.>>%outputFile%
```

It will create a text file `log-change-history.txt` in the repo folder on the server and append each log change notification.

Comment: Great solution. To be compatible to your suggested source the variable names have to be adapted. And the label where to copy it is named :eof.

Answer (score 2):

For PC users:
The .bat extension did not work for me when used on Windows Server maching. I used VisualSvn as Django Reinhardt suggested, and it created a hook with a .cmd extension.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to SVN repo directory into the subfolder "hooks", e.g. "D:\SVN\hooks\"
2. create the empty file "pre-revprop-change.bat" there
3. in the file write "exit 0" (without "") and save it
4. enjoy :)

(This solution surely has drawbacks, as nothing is checked/prohibited. But for my case - a local repo that only I am using - it seems to work.)

Answer (score 2):

This was the easiest for me on a Windows Server:
In VisualSVN right-click your repository, then select **Properties...** and then the  **Hooks** tab.

Select **Pre-revision property change hook**, click **Edit**.

I needed to be able to change the Author - it often happens on remote computers used by multiple people, that by mistake we check-in using someone else's stored credentials.

Here is the modified community wiki script to paste:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Set all parameters. Even though most are not used, in case you want to add
:: changes that allow, for example, editing of the author or addition of log messages.
set repository=%1
set revision=%2
set userName=%3
set propertyName=%4
set action=%5

:: Only allow the author to be changed, but not message ("svn:log"), etc.
if /I not "%propertyName%" == "svn:author" goto ERROR_PROPNAME

:: Only allow modification of a log message, not addition or deletion.
if /I not "%action%" == "M" goto ERROR_ACTION

:: Make sure that the new svn:log message is not empty.
set bIsEmpty=true
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('find /V ""') do (
set bIsEmpty=false
)
if "%bIsEmpty%" == "true" goto ERROR_EMPTY

goto :eof

:ERROR_EMPTY
echo Empty svn:author messages are not allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_PROPNAME
echo Only changes to svn:author messages are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_ACTION
echo Only modifications to svn:author revision properties are allowed. >&2
goto ERROR_EXIT

:ERROR_EXIT
exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alois Helmer answered before, you need to locate the file `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` in the `hooks` directory inside the SVN repository you want to allow revision comments edition.

For me, to create a copy with `pre-revprop-change name` was sufficient, though you could edit it to allow only certain users to modify the comments or some other needs you have.

And then you must grant regular read and execution permissions using `chmod 755 pre-revprop-change`

But **regular execution permissions are not enough**.  You need to **give Apache/HTTPD execution grants in SELinux for that script** like this.

```
chcon -t httpd_exec_t pre-revprop-change
```

If you not, you'll get the following error that gives little information and it's hard to relate to a SELinux conf.

```
svnrdump: E175008: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code 255) with no output.
```