# svnrdump: E135007: Write error in pipe

Tags: svn

I am trying to move a folder from a subversion repository to another while keeping all of its histories intact and these are the commands I used:

```
svnrdump dump -r0:HEAD http://asvn/original_repo/sub_folder_A | svnrdump load http://asvn/new_repo/sub_folder_A
```

the *dump* command itself works well but I am getting the following error when I try to use the *load* command:

> svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-r
>   evprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
>   svnrdump: E175002: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code
>   1) with output:
>
> ** ERROR-FILES: Unable to get revision (0) file list:
>                   'svnlook.exe: missing argument: r Type
>                   'svnlook help' for usage.'
>
> svnrdump: E135007: Write error in pipe

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335346/pre-revprop-change-hook-either-failed) and added a pre-revprop-change.bat with *exit 0* as suggested but I am getting a new error:

> svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the repository's pre-r
>   evprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
>
> svnrdump: E175002: Revprop change blocked by pre-revprop-change hook (exit code
>   1) with output:
>
> ** ERROR-FILES: Unable to get revision (0) file list:
>                   'svnlook.exe: missing argument: r Type
>                   'svnlook help' for usage.'

Have any of you came across this issue and know the solution to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Pre-revprop-change hook script seems to be broken on target repository.

Comment: @bahrep, I have updated my question with the errors that I encounter when trying to fix the pre-revprop change hook script error. exit 0 doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: I'm going to check and post an answer in 24 hours. Thank you for the new info.

Comment: @bahrep thank you! I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found this link and added a pre-revprop-change.bat with exit 0 as
>   suggested but I am getting a new error:

I guess that you actually mix up the *target* and *source* repositories. The error that you see is coming from the *target* repository and it 100% has a pre-revprop-hook script that's broken in some way. It appears that the hook script has invalid `svnlook` command:

`svnlook.exe: missing argument: r Type 'svnlook help' for usage.`

Comment: hmm..the error messages were received after committing the pre-revprop-hook script was committed to the target repository.

Comment: @May I'm 100% sure that there is a problem with this script. You don't normally commit the script to the repository, it has to be in $repo/hooks directory on the file system where the repository resides.

Comment: you're right, it's the hook. I am able to dump the load to the target repository now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @may great! I'm glad it helped. BTW, you could accept my answer by clicking Tick icon and also upvote it. ;)