# Trying to do svn import over ssh

Tags: svn, version-control, ssh

I am trying to do import a directory over from a cluster and create a local trunk. I am trying to use svn+ssh to do this.

```
svn import svn+ssh://user@cluster:/path/to/file file:///path/to/svn/repo/trunk -m "Initial import from cluster"
svn: 'svn+ssh://user@cluster:/path/to/file' does not exist
```

Is there something wrong with this command? To clarify any initial questions about connectivity, I can log into the cluster using ssh without any problems, and the path to file is correct. The local repository is working and has other branches in it, which I locally commit to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need the : after user@cluster on your svn+ssh:// URL.

Second of all you can't use import to copy from one repository to another.

I'd recommend either svnrdump or svnsync for this task.

To use svnsync you'd do something like this:

```
svnadmin create repo
echo '#!/bin/sh' > repo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
echo 'exit 0' >> repo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
chmod a+x repo/hooks/pre-revprop-change
svnsync init file://`pwd`/repo svn+ssh://user@cluster/path/to/repo
svnsync sync file://`pwd`/repo
```

Or with svnrdump:

```
svnadmin create repo
svnrdump svn+ssh://user@cluster/path/to/repo | svnadmin load repo
```

svnsync is probably the best way to do things if you want to continue to keep a mirror of the repository locally since you can just run the sync command in the future to update the repository to match the other side.  Note that committing other changes to the local repo will break the ability to continue to do this.  You can read more about svnsync here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication

The svnsync directions assume a unix environment.  If you're on Windows you probably need to replace the bit about the pre-revprop-change hook with a bat file.  You can find some details here:
[What is a pre-revprop-change hook in SVN, and how do I create it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197224/what-is-a-pre-revprop-change-hook-in-svn-and-how-do-i-create-it)

svnrdump is probably better if you want to just fork the repo and work on it separately locally.  You can read more about svnrdump here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump

Ideally we'd have better support for cross repository merging, which might be more along the lines of what you're actually looking for but I don't have a good solution for that.  There is this rather horrible method of doing vendor branches:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html

Comment: Thanks for this, I am trying to create a branch on the local machine, and I am not trying to copy repo to repo, I am trying to import the directory into a repo (As a first commit). I could ideally copy the directory, create a branch locally, create a repo on the cluster, and then do what you have done here. But is that the only way, because, as you said, it is quite ugly itself.

Comment: I'm not sure if you actually control the svn+ssh:// repository.  But honestly, Subversion is not made for this sort of forking.  You're much better off just using `svn cp` to make a branch on the server rather than trying to make a local branch.  If you control both sides then using a distributed version control system may be desirable (e.g. git, mercurial).

Comment: I control the 'svn+ssh://' repository, but I see what you are saying. I think I'll stick with svn for now, and try to play around with what all I can do. If nothing works out, I'll try porting to git. Thanks!