# Edit a log entry on Subversion after COMMIT

Tags: svn

Is there any means to modify a Subversion log entry, *after* COMMIT, and without resorting to server-side work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are two types of properties In Subversion. One is a file property. This is part of a file or directory and is versioned with the file. Another property is the *revison property*. This property is placed on the revision change itself and is not versioned.

Three special revision properties are set at the time of commit. One is `svn:log` which is the commit message. Another is `svn:author` which is the id do the user who did the commit, and the last is the `svn:date` Which is when the commit was made.

Since these properties are not versioned, changing the value could be disastrous. You could hide the author of a change, change the date, or why the change was made. Therefore, Subversion does not allow anyone to change these properties without permission.

You grant permission via a pre-revprop-change hook. And you can use this hook to limit who can make a change. In many hooks:

- Only the `svn:log` property can be changed.
- Only the author of the commit or the SVN Admin is allowed to change the `svn:log` property.

A template pre-revprop-change template hook is created in the `hooks` directory of the repository that does these two items.  Many sites simply use that template script. However, I've seen sites do other things.

- Limit the amount of time you're allowed to change the commit message. Maybe allow someone an hour window to change it.
- Keep a log of the changes.
- Make sure changes in the `svn:log` revprop match the chess age in a system like Jenkins.

Once you have the pre-revprop-change hook activated, you can change the message with the following command:

```
$ svn propedit --revprop -r $REV "new commit message"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible if the repository administrator has enabled revision property editing via the [pre-revprop-change hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html). By default, this action is denied.

See also:

- [What is a pre-revprop-change hook in SVN, and how do I create it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197224/what-is-a-pre-revprop-change-hook-in-svn-and-how-do-i-create-it)
- http://www.wandisco.com/svnforum/threads/39203-Pre-revprop-change-shell-script-allows-commiters-to-change-own-log-within-X-hours