# Editing a Log in tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can you edit a log if you made a mistake when specifying some commit comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the log messages window (Show Log), right click on log message and choose "Edit log message".

Comment: I get this error though: "a DAV request failed; It's possible that the repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existet"  oh well.  Thanks for that did not see it before.

Comment: You may need to add a hook for property changes; I had this error after upgrading from 1.4 to 1.6.

Comment: Other team members may have to refresh the TortoiseSVN log cache by Ctrl+F5 in order to see the changes.

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-refresh

Answer (score 10):

By default, you cannot edit the log message. In order to change this default behavior, you (or your SVN administrator) need to set up an appropriate pre-revprop-change hook.

The online "[Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html)" book describes what a [pre-revprop-change hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) is and how to set one up.

[This StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin) has pre-revprop-change content that you can cut-and-paste to enable log message edits.