# In TortoiseSVN, add comment after commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I go back and edit comments on an SVN checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin)

Once in a rare while I inadvertently commit a file without commenting (we're supposed to comment on every commit no matter how trivial the change). Is there a way to add a comment after committing without reverting and recommitting?

Comment: Rather than being supposed to do this, you could see if the administrator can install a commit hook on the server to prevent commits without comments.

Comment: Thanks @RedFilter. @SteveMc, in a functional work environment, that'd be a great idea. ;-)

Comment: manojlds (see below) makes a great suggestion. I had forgotten that you can make a local pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from doing a `propset` on `svn:log` using something like below as suggested from [Can I go back and edit comments on an SVN checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin/692875#692875):

```
svn propset --revprop -r 1000 svn:log "Not blank"
```

you should consider creating a pre-commit hook that will prevent you from checking in without a commit message. This can be on the server **or even on your local copy**. Screenshot, since you are using TortoiseSVN:

[image]

After all, prevention is better than cure!

Sample pre-commit to prevent committing with no commit message:

```
for %%I in (%3) Do (
IF %%~zI==0 (
echo "No commit message given" 1>&2
exit 1
)
)
```

My bash knowledge is limited, but the above seems to work. You can of course have a script in Python, Ruby etc. if needed. Basically, the third parameter is a temporary file that contains the commit message. See if it is empty and exit if so.

Comment: Thanks @manojlds. I like this idea and am trying to find documentation on how to do it but am not finding much. I found a couple of samples: 
http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/client-side/PreCommit.js.tmpl 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin/692875#693032 
but I'd like some kind of API or manual that shows me the possible options. Any idea how to check for empty comments or where I can look to find that info?

Comment: @squidbe - have updated my answer with a sample hook

Comment: Thanks @manojlds. I get an error when using that script: "The hook script returned an error."  Informative, eh? ;-)
Can you point me to whatever resource you used to get compose that script? I'll do the digging; I just need to know where to dig.

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg), there is a mechanism available using the `pre-revprop-change` hook, or the `svnadmin setlog` command (if you have local access to the repository, which I suspect you don't), however in a team environment I would suggest that the revert & recommit is probably a better choice.

Comment: Thanks @Richard, after reading what's involved, I'm afraid you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider both of these as best practices:

1. Require comments on commit *(pre-commit hook needed)*
2. Allow editing of existing comments *(pre-revprop-change hook needed)*

I find the latter useful because it allows you to go back and revise poorly written, inaccurate, or just plain bad (e.g. "Fixed" :-) messages.

Regarding the former, it is best to install on the server--that way it applies to everyone automatically. If you require users to set it up on the client side, you run the chance of a new user forgetting to do so.

Installing a hook is as simple as placing a hook script in the hooks directory of the repository. In fact, when you create a repository it populates the hooks directory with sample hook scripts; they are in Unix/Linux shell script, though, so if your server is Windows-based you need to find (or write) other versions. As it happens, the SO question [Common Types of Subversion Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155/common-types-of-subversion-hooks/) provides Windows versions of a few hooks including both of those mentioned above.

For full details on Subversion hooks, see [Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) in Chapter 5 of [the Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) for server side and [Client Side Hook Scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) in Chapter 4 of [the TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) for client side.