# is there a way to fix a mistake in the comment on an svn commit?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I go back and edit comments on an SVN checkin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin)

I've seen plenty of cases where someone put an inaccurate comment on an SVN commit. It would be nice if there was a way to clean these up.

Okay, I think the answer is "not without doing a dump and restore", but maybe I'm lucky and there is an easy way.

Comment: Yes. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692851/can-i-go-back-and-edit-comments-on-an-svn-checkin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the answer you seek:

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#change-log-msg

Answer (score 0):

The [svnadmin setlog](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setlog.html) command can do this.