# Modifying a commit message

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, ubersvn

I have a local run ubersvn repository in my computer and I would like to modify a commit message that I have on my last commit. Is there anyway through ubersvn or tortoisesvn (which I use as an interface) to change the commit message of a previous commit? I am an admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update SVN old commit comment/log-message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862830/how-to-update-svn-old-commit-comment-log-message) ... on this other post you will see my answer showing you how to enable log message editing from TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TurtoiseSvn - Show log -> Edit log message.

Comment: When I try that, I will get an error saying "DAV Require failed; it's possible that the repositories pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent.

Answer (score 2):

Commit log message is property of revision `svn:log`, which you can, as any other svn-property, edit with `svn propedit`.

PS: and viewed with proplist

```
>svn proplist --revprop -r "HEAD" http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/ -v
Unversioned properties on revision 34:
  svn:author
    lazybadger
  svn:date
    2012-03-24T06:28:12.536500Z
  svn:log
    Added file with vowels in filename
```