# Is there a way to add comments entered using TortoiseSVN during a commit to a C# source file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to capture all comments and dates entered by my team while committing their changes and append them to the source file (C#). I know svn:keywords allows you to capture some metadata but it gets updated each time a commit is executed.

In my previous job we had CVS configured to do exactly that. Was wondering if I can do the same with SVN.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably using pre-commit-hook.

You can find out more about it at [Subersion hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks)

This discussion is also talk a lot of different hooks [Q: Common typs of subersion hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155/common-types-of-subversion-hooks)