# SVN author independent of login

Tags: svn

Is this possible to have author screen name (visible in logs, blame etc) different than login?
It would be equivalent to hg `[ui] username`.
Multiple users are using same login to svn and I cant change this (sick, I know).
We use tortoise svn on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reset all passwords in SVN server, reset login cache in Tortoise (Settings > Saved Data > Authentication data > Clear), and tell users not to auto-save user credentials. Since there are no passwords users would have to type in only their usernames.

Edit:

Revision's author name is a property of revision than can be changed. TortoiseSVN > Show Log > right-click a revision > Edit author. You can put any string there. You only have to allow this editing with the hook. Hook's path is `<your_repository>/hooks/pre-revprop-change.bat` and in the simplest and most careless way it could contain just `exit 0` and nothing more. This would allow editing all properties, like svn:author, svn:log, svn:date, and all the less important ones. If you want to allow only editing authors then take [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850/395718) and replace `svn:log` with `svn:author`.

Comment: I suggest that instead of single user you have several users, so that users are forced to enter their names (but passwords are blank). Is that feasible for your case?

Comment: Nope. Users must use shared login and password. Is there equivalent for hg `username` setting in svn?

Comment: Shared username is really (REALLY) bad idea. Having said that maybe you could use SlikSVN command line app in post-commit hook of TortoiseSVN to change the author. But I recommend having multiple accounts. What is the explanation why users must use shared username?

Comment: I can think of a reason. If the local copy exists in a network share, multiple people can contribute to the changes, but only person who checked out the copy can commit or do anything with that copy.

Comment: @seler There is a username setting. But I've gotten conflicts sometimes in pre-1.7.1 builds specifying a different name each time.